# Ok to share public key from code signing certificate?

Tags: code-signing, gpo

I'm quite sure I know the answer to this question already, but I'd hate to be wrong.  I have a Code Signing Cert from a CA and want to share the public key to make it easier for IT people to add me to Trusted Publishers for MS Office, e.g. via Group Policy.

So - paranoid that I might share the wrong thing, I ran my code on a 'clean' PC and, via macro security, added the cert to the trusted publishers.  Then from Internet Explorer I 'successfully' exported the certificate as DER Encoded Binary (.CER).

I'd imagine that the resulting file is the PUBLIC part of the certificate and the Cert:

- could, without additional risk, be shared on a website
- is equivalent to what a anyone else would end up with if they
  followed the same steps
- can be installed using GPO (or whatever is used)

Can someone confirm whether or not all this is ok (or am I justified in my paranoia / setting myself up for problems)?

Are there any other steps that I need to know? I want to give the Cert to a client so they can bulk install for all their users...

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes - it is OK, necessary even, to share this information.